# Fastest Formats for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, performance

Our organization is going to be publishing many maps with multiple types of layers on ArcGIS Online through an ESRI institutional account.  What types considerations are there when publishing content in this way?  Specifically we are considering speed for the end user of the maps and also credits used for those layers stored on that account.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use ArcGIS Online is not to use ArcGIS Online. ;) But, if you must:

- Ensure that your data are in the Web Mercator projection
- [Generalize](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/generalize.htm) your features to reduce the number of vertices and therefore the size/complexity of your data
- Delete any unnecessary attribute fields; if they aren't used by your end-users or by the application, then they only take up space
- Use the simplest data type possible for each attribute (e.g., don't store numbers in a string field; just make it a numeric field instead)

  - Use coded value domains where possible
- It's a balance, but you can dissolve features to eliminate redundant table entries

I'm sure there are other tips and tricks, but these are the big ones.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, good call. I was taking that one for granted.

Comment: Uh-oh. Got a down-vote. Would appreciate a correction or an alternative answer.